# Find the flux of the surface $S$ is part of the helicoid $z = \theta$ that lies inside the cylinder $r = 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let **F** denote the vector field **F**$(x,y,z) = \langle y,-x,z \rangle $ Find the flux of **F** across the surface S, where:

The surface $S$ is part of the helicoid $z = \theta$ that lies inside the cylinder $r = 1$ and in the first octant, and is oriented upwards. Here, $(r,\theta,z)$ are cylindrical coordinates.

My attempt:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 0 ,\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1} (\theta r) dr d\theta$$

$$= \frac{\pi^2}{16}$$

Is this correct approach? If not can someone please show me.

Comment: Where did you get those partial derivatives? And how are you parametrizing the surface and computing the flux?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Are those not the correct partial derivatives? I thought I was suppose to get partial derivates of x and y from my z function

Comment: Write $\theta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ as $\theta=\arctan (y/x)$

Comment: Better yet, parametrize the surface by $(r,\theta)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin ok, but how do you parameterize by $(r,\theta)$ when all you have is $z = \theta$

Comment: You're using polar/cylindrical coordinates, of course.